# Error message: Field requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.os.AsyncTask#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

Tags: android, eclipse, android-asynctask

```
@Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    buttonDOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            final Sender messageSender = new Sender(); // Initialize chat sender AsyncTask.
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                                messageSender.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                            } else {
                                messageSender.execute();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

I wanted to send messages from phone to computer
I found myself ready example, but when I threw it in the project it gives red line error.
Does anyone know a solution to fix errors?

Answer (score 1):

Add `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)` as an annotation on this method, to indicate that you have (AFAYK) correctly implemented it with respect to API Level 11.